# How to Pass Data Mat-Dialog

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

So I'm trying to pass data that i input in dialog and send it back to the parent component my problem is how to patch the value of array in the afterclosed? i tried the patchvalue and the setvalue and it wont show? anyone can help me

> MAT DIALOG

```
OnInit(): void {
    this.fg = this.fb.group({
      id: [],
      qty: [],
      displayArray: this.fb.array([this.CreateItem()]),
    });
    this.fg.get('qty').valueChanges.subscribe((res) => {
      for (let i = this.displayArray.length; i < res; i++) {
        this.displayArray.push(this.CreateItem());
      }
    });
    this.data = this.fg.get('qty').setValue(this.data.qty);
  }

  CreateItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      MoreItem: [''],
    });
  }
  get displayArray(): FormArray {
    return this.fg.get('displayArray') as FormArray;
  }
  inMemoryList() {
    this.http.get<MyDTO>('api/users').subscribe((test) => (this.myDTO = test));
  }
  save() {
    this.dialogRef.close([this.data.qty]);
  }
```

> MY PARENT COMPONENT

```
  CreatesetItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      ListItem: [''],
    });
  }
  item(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      qty: [],
      name: [''],
    });
  }
  get setItem(): FormArray {
    return this.fg.get('setItem') as FormArray;
  }
  get Info(): FormArray {
    return this.fg.get('Info') as FormArray;
  }
  openAlertDialog(index: number) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AlertDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        qty: this.fg.value.Info[index].qty,
        name: this.fg.value.Info[index].name,
      },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < result; i++) {
        this.setItem.push(this.CreatesetItem());
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < result; i++) {
        this.setItem.at(i).patchValue({ qty: result.qty });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add (change) even on dropdown select and then populate the values to those empty boxes using [(ngModel)]="variable"

### app.html

```
<select (change)="setSelectedItem($event)"> 
  <option>option1</ng-option>
  <option>option2</ng-option> 
</select>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="field1" name="field1">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="field2" name="field2">
```

### app.component.ts

```
// declare variables

field1: string;
field2: string;

// dropdown on change function

setSelectedItem(event) {
  
  // set values to those variables
  this.field1 = "Hi";
  this.field2 = "Hello";

}
```

Comment: what if your using 2 components?

Comment: @mimisxz
Then create a child-parent relationship and use @Input() in other component. 
It will be better if you can elaborate on your use case properly and add the minimum code so that we can understand what you’re trying to do.